# Zend Framework 2 DB Adapter setup

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to set up DB ADAPTER in Zend Framework 2 like as DB ADAPTER in Zend Framework 1.

IN ZF1 bootstrap.php I've

```
protected function _initDatabase() {
    $this->bootstrap('db');
    $dbResource = $this->getResource('db');
    Zend_Registry::set(ESIGN_REGISTRY_KEY_DB, $dbResource);
}
```

and in application.ini

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.dbname = "DB NAME"
resources.db.params.host = "HOST"
resources.db.params.username = "DB USER"
resources.db.params.password = "DB PASSWORD"
```

In my application I can use

```
$dbAdapter = Zend_Registry::get('db');
```

and get DB ADAPTER.

Please help me to config it in ZF2.
Thanks.

Comment: ZF2 has a completely different architecture to prior versions; forget singletons and [make sure to read the documentation](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/tutorial.dbadapter.html).

Comment: Thank you for answer, but in ZF2 you can use it, only I can't use my global and local configs in model. In controller I can call it via $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
As I need to run custom query.

Comment: Here is documentation  http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can do this and it depends on how you're structuring your application really. But the following is assuming you have everything setup correctly for the db adapter in you config file.

So you could do this somewhere,

```
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature;

// note, $sm is the service manager here
GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($sm->get('adapter_alias_name'));
```

The `alias` is set in your config file like:

```
// both of these are from factories in the `service manager` key in the config file.
'aliases' => array(
    'adapter_alias_name1' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter1',
    'adapter_alias_name2' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter2',
)
```

Anyway, continuing, to get the static adapter you would then use:

```
\Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::getStaticAdapter();
```

That might be all you need, but you could also create a class that your models could extend, that would have the db adapter in it.

For example something like:

```
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\RowGatewayFeature;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature;

abstract class AbstractTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->featureSet = new Feature\FeatureSet();
        $this->featureSet->addFeature(new Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature());
        $this->featureSet->addFeature(new Feature\RowGatewayFeature($this->primary));
        $this->featureSet->setTableGateway($this);
        $this->featureSet->apply('preInitialize', array());

        // view your adapter settings
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($this->adapter, true) . '</pre>;die;
    }
}
```

Then your models could just extend that class and the adapter would already be set. Hopefully that makes sense and helps some. I've seen this implemented in a lot of different ways.

Comment: Could you provide 1 or 2 example on how it is implemented? A link to a resource is also fine.